# Save cookie using jQuery

Tags: jquery, cookies, frontend

I'm trying to make some sort of switch. A radio button that when switched toggles a class on certain divs. At least thet's the idea. I can do this with jQuery easily but my problem is making it stay after a refresh. For example, if I switch the... switch, it would remove `.filter` from all `.post`. I want to make the switch stay like that after refresh. Is there a way I can acheive this only using jQuery and without access to back end stuff?

Comment: look at a plugin like https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Comment: Why don't you set the cookie using javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Arun P Johny said, you can use jquery cookie, but using a plugin just for this kind of purpose is not very usefull.

Know you want in only jQuery, but the implementation in javascript is very simple, so I'll show you anyway (with a session cookie) :

```
$("#button").click(function(){
    document.cookie = "toggled=yes";
});

if (document.cookie.indexOf("toggled") >= 0){
    $(".post").removeClass(".filter");
}
```

Comment: Okay I'm accepting this answer because I'd actually prefer not using a plugin. I'm just not so sure what you mean but your answer looks pretty jQuery to me(rather than vanilla js). Thanks for it anyway! On a related note, sorry because I'm really new to cookies, does it work on other part of the domain? For example, if a user toggled the switch on `example.com`, would the cookie be available to `example.com/somepage`?

Comment: Yeah If course it works on all the domain :) First I create a cookie called toggled when the button is clicked and after I check if the cookie exists and I remove the class :)

Answer (score 0):

I love this jQuery plugin: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

Save cookie when radio button toggled:

```
$.cookie('COOKIE_NAME', option_to_save , { expires: 365, path: '/' });
```

And get cookie before DOM ready, then initialize your certain DIVs:

```
var option = $.cookie('COOKIE_NAME')
```